# Create a new AWS project in PhpStorm

Tags: amazon-web-services, phpstorm

To create an AWS::Lambda that I can test locally.

I was following this tutorial until this part: https://youtu.be/31Wih42FqTM?t=249 (timecode set).

I have `AWS Toolkit` plugin:

[image]

Problem:

1. I don't have `AWS` option in `New Project`

[image]

I'm working on PhpStorm, it's because of that?

**Answer**: Finaly, I need `Intellij idea`:

[image]

Comment: *"I'm working on PhpStorm, it's because of that?"* No/unlikely. The video talks about "AWS Toolkit", must be about a plugin. Do you have it?  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11349-aws-toolkit

Comment: I forgot to mention this but yes, I have AWS Toolkit plugin.

Comment: In a video I do not see PHP support. Plus, it uses Python there that PhpStorm does not support. Although you could use Node.js so it still should be possible to use it in PhpStorm... Sorry, I do not know and cannot help here (I've only commented as I have seen the chance of "maybe it forgot to install the plugin").

Comment: What PhpStorm and what plugin version do you have? I [can't reproduce](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PAvG7V7-hkZ0yuh5aaIpIuieQnCphwmp/view?usp=drivesdk) that on 2022.3 with plugin version 1.57-223

Comment: @EugeneMorozov : PhpStorm 2022.3 Runtime version: 17.0.5+1-b653.14 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o. and plugin AWS Toolkit

Comment: @Mitsukk You have much fewer entries in the New Project window than I do. Do you have many plugins disabled?